# Moving a deep-set member of a multidimensional array tree - using lodash or underscore

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, underscore.js, lodash

I want to move a deep set member of a tree using lodash or equivalent code.

**Example Tree**

```
[
    { id: 32, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    { id: 43, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    { id: 55, name: 'unique name', children: [
        { id: 31, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        { id: 63, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        { id: 84, name: 'unique name', children: [
            { id: 47, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
            { id: 56, name: 'unique name', children: [] }
        ] }
    ] }
    { id: 67, name: 'unique name', children: [
        { id: 78, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        { id: 89, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    ] },
    { id: 30, name: 'unique name', children: [] }
]
```

How can I:

- Locate the specific object with id: 47
- move that object (with id: 47) to a new level of the tree

Would preferably use lodash. Tree can be of infinite depth.

---

**EDIT** In response to the chosen answer i re-worked the code to more accurately fit my question description: https://jsfiddle.net/j88vencp/4/

---

Comment: your `data` is not correct? Shows syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** you can change the structure of your tree slightly it would be must easier to operate on in the way you want:

```
var collection = {
    32 : { id: 32, name: 'unique name', children: {} },
    43: { id: 43, name: 'unique name', children: {} },
    55: { id: 55, name: 'unique name', children: {
      31: { id: 31, name: 'unique name', children: {} },
      63: { id: 63, name: 'unique name', children: {} },
      84: { id: 84, name: 'unique name', children: {
           47: { id: 47, name: 'unique name', children: {} },
           56: { id: 56, name: 'unique name', children: {} },
        } },
    } }
}

function moveElement(el, obj) {
    var newEl = el;
    var id = el.id;
    // do removing and moving stuff here
    console.log(newEl);
    // remove from collection
    _.omit(obj, el.id);
    // add to collection in upper tree
    obj[id] = newEl;
    console.log(obj);
}

function deepSearch(obj, origobj, val) {

  for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var el = obj[key];
          if (_.size(el.children) > 0) {
              deepSearch(el.children, origobj, val);
          }
          if (key == val) {
              moveElement(el, origobj);
              return;
          }   
      }    
  }

}

deepSearch(collection, collection, 56);
```

here is a fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/j88vencp/4/

Comment: will findKey() search through nested deep arrays?

Comment: could you show a small example in the answer .. :-)

Comment: you can actually do it without using _.findKey see my updated answer

Comment: That works perfectly! i will update the question to be clearer.

Comment: You might want to use something like `_.each(_.values(obj), function(el) { ... })` instead of `for ... in`. Then you can avoid the whole `hasOwnProperty()` check and `el` assignment.

Comment: @AdamBoduch Jip thanks for that, you should probably use lodash instead of vanilla js since it's available, that for loop has been drilled into my brain....;)